# How to align columns of a text file in java?

Tags: java, string, text-alignment

I have a text file with 8 columns. These columns have to be left aligned. I have tried it using the Formatter.format(). But it did not work. The file is..

```
test.txt        0      0        ছোট       JJ      B-JJP      o        -

test.txt        0      1        ছেলের      NN      B-NP       o        -

test.txt        0      2        জন্মতিথি     NN      B-NP       o       -
```

and The code which one I tried is..

```
/****s1,s2.. contains the token(string) of each line of the file***/
fm.format("%-25s  %-3s  %3s  %-30s  %-5s  %-8s %-20s  %-15s",
    s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8);

str=fm.toString();
line.set(i, str);
```

Comment: please edit your question with some better formatting to better illustrate exactly what your code outputs and what you wish the output to look like.

Answer (score 2):

The Bengali font you are using is not monospaced (fixed-width characters).  The results you are seeing are normal; try outputting English text with a non-monospace font and you will see similar results.

There is no way to output this to a terminal and achieve the desired spacing.  You need to use an output method that is graphics-based, and that can position each output column at a fixed location (i.e. PDF).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have to output it to a text file and cannot use graphics-based because this one is a part of file based(I have to modify the input file with appropriate spacing) project. Have tried this using English text and it worked. But I have to do the same thing with strings with Bengali font.

Comment: Unless you can find a fixed-width Bengali font this will be impossible.  A quick Google search for "fixed width Bengali font" turned up [Bangla OpenType Font](http://ekushey.org/?page/solaimanlipi).  Not being a Bengali speaker, I don't know if this will work for you.